# public.<my_table> does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, greenplum

Say I have a temporary table `my_table`, and I would like add a column to it that acts as a primary key.

I have tried with:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;
UPDATE my_table SET id = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table','id'));
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

but the first line complains with:

```
ERROR: relation"public.my_table" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

will work fine.

The problem isn't your query. It's that the table does not exist. Perhaps it's a temporary table in another session? Temporary tables are only visible within the session that created them.

Comment: Thanks. Trying the above returns: `Cannot add column with primary key constraint`

Comment: @user815423426 PostgreSQL version?